# How to modify and add an extra legend in a ggplot2 figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this:

```
example.df <- as.data.frame(matrix( c("height","fruit",0.2,0.4,0.7,
                                      "height","veggies",0.3,0.6,0.8,
                                      "height","exercise",0.1,0.2,0.5,
                                      "bmi","fruit",0.2,0.4,0.6,
                                      "bmi","veggies",0.1,0.5,0.7,
                                      "bmi","exercise",0.4,0.7,0.8,
                                      "IQ","fruit",0.4,0.5,0.6,
                                      "IQ","veggies",0.3,0.5,0.7,
                                      "IQ","exercise",0.1,0.4,0.6), 
                                    nrow=9, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE))

colnames(example.df) <- c("phenotype","predictor","corr1","corr2","corr3")
```

So basically three different correlations between 3x3 variables. I want to visualize the increase in correlations as follows:

```
ggplot(example.df, aes(x=phenotype, y=corr1, yend=corr3, colour = predictor)) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(x = phenotype, 
                     ymin = corr1, ymax = corr3, 
                     colour = predictor), 
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
  geom_point(size = 3,
             aes(x = phenotype, y = corr1, colour = predictor),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), shape=4)+
  geom_point(size = 3, 
             aes(x = phenotype, y = corr2, colour = predictor),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), shape=18)+
  geom_point(size = 3,
             aes(x = phenotype, y = corr3, colour = predictor),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, 
       title="Stackoverflow Example Plot")+
  scale_colour_manual(name="", values=c("#4682B4", "#698B69", "#FF6347"))+
  theme_minimal()
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

Problems:

1. Tthere is something wrong with the way the `geom_point` shapes are dodged with BMI and IQ. They should be all with on the line with the same colour, like with height.
2. How do I get an extra legend that can show what the circle, cross, and square represent? (i.e., the three different correlations shown on the line: cross = correlation 1, square = correlation 2, circle = correlation 3).
3. The legend now shows a line, circle, cross through each other, while just a line for the predictors (exercise, fruit, veggies) would suffice..

Sorry for the multiple issues, but adding the extra legend (problem #2) is the most important one, and I would be already very satisfied if that could be solved, the rest is bonus! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if the following works for you? The main idea is to convert the data frame from wide to long format for the `geom_point` layer, and map correlation as a shape aesthetic:

```
example.df %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = phenotype, color = predictor, group = predictor)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = corr1, ymax = corr3),
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% tidyr::gather(corr, value, -phenotype, -predictor),
             aes(y = value, shape = corr),
             size = 3,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#4682B4", "#698B69", "#FF6347")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(4, 18, 16),
                     labels = paste("correlation", 1:3)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, color = "", shape = "") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: plot]

Note: The colour legend is based on both `geom_linerange` and `geom_point`, hence the legend keys include both a line and a point shape. While it's possible to get rid of the second one, it does take some more convoluted code, and I don't think the plot would be much improved as a result...